# Linear Algebra - Vector Subspace of Polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Given that $n=4$, how can you show that the subset of real polynomials whose graphs touch the $x$-axis tangentially at $x=0$ and $x=1$ is a vector subspace? Then give its dimension.

$\Longrightarrow $ I went about this at first by stating that the polynomial must have stationary points at $x=0$ and $x=1$:

$$f(x) = a_1x^4 + a_2x^5+\ldots+a_nx^n$$
$$f'(x) = 4a_1x^3 + 5a_2x^4+\ldots+na_nx^{n-1}$$

- Let $f(x) = 0$ when $x=0$ or $x=1$;
- Then I said in this case this is true for any $a_1\ldots a_n$ when $x=0$;
- And for $x=1$: $a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n = 0$;

Is this correct so far, if so how do I go about showing that this is a vector subspace and how would I write that formally.

Comment: In the future, use $\LaTeX$ for your formulae

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Convince yourself that $f(x)=ax^2(x-1)^2$, $a\in\boldsymbol R$.